# If statement for form validation

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form here and I was wondering if anyone could show me how to make this happen:

When the person clicks submit, it must check that they have put something for every question, if not it must give an error. If it has then it can say thank you for participating and send the email.

Comment: You should clearly mention which google search didnt render any results for you... Stackoverflow is for solving problems, not for teaching you programming.

Answer (score 1):

Although you normally show the code you already have, this is what you need:

```
$question1 = $_POST['question1'];
$valid = true;
$errors = array();

if(empty($question1)){//question not filled in
    $valid = false;
    $errors['question1'] = true;
}

//if you want to check amount of characters
if(strlen($question1) <= 1){ // minimum entry is 2 characters
    $valid = false;
    $errors['question1'] = true;
}

if($valid == true){
//it worked! you filled everything in!
}else{
//you did not fill every field, try again
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add required property to all your inputs (basic)
2. Use the jQuery Validate Plugin([link](http://jqueryvalidation.org)) (recommended)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this client side, then you can just add the *required* attribute to your input fields.

If you want to do it server side, then the easiest I guess is to loop through your post variable:

```
$bIsValid = true;
foreach($_POST as $fld => $val){
    if($val = ''){
        $bIsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The required attribute is quite useless if you work with form. For example, if you need to fill in a name, a string length of less than 2 should give an error as well, since it is no valid name.

Comment: @Saypontigohe : Strange comment. It is indeed useless if you want to check that at least two characters are filled. But the OP just wanted to know if the field was filled at all. The required attribute does exactly that.